# Maven Emma coverage Report failed

Tags: maven, report, emma

Hi i want to generate emma report using maven.when i try to build report it gives this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (default) on project point-repo: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument failed: CONSTANT_info: invalid tag value [18] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (default) on project point-repo: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument failed: CONSTANT_info: invalid tag value [18]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument failed: CONSTANT_info: invalid tag value [18]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CONSTANT_info: invalid tag value [18]
    at com.vladium.jcd.cls.constant.CONSTANT_info.new_CONSTANT_info(CONSTANT_info.java:103)
    at com.vladium.jcd.parser.ClassDefParser$classParser.constant_pool(ClassDefParser.java:168)
    at com.vladium.jcd.parser.ClassDefParser$classParser.class_table(ClassDefParser.java:109)
    at com.vladium.jcd.parser.ClassDefParser.parseClass(ClassDefParser.java:56)
    at com.vladium.emma.instr.InstrProcessorST.handleFile(InstrProcessorST.java:468)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:193)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumeratePathDir(IPathEnumerator.java:177)
    at com.vladium.util.IPathEnumerator$Factory$PathEnumerator.enumerate(IPathEnumerator.java:97)
    at com.vladium.emma.instr.InstrProcessorST._run(InstrProcessorST.java:715)
    at com.vladium.emma.Processor.run(Processor.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.emma.task.InstrumentTask.execute(InstrumentTask.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.emma.EmmaInstrumentMojo.doExecute(EmmaInstrumentMojo.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.emma.AbstractEmmaMojo.execute(AbstractEmmaMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 24 more
[ERROR]
```

And this is the way i have added plugin to maven.I just only generate code coverage report to my test cases.Is there any one got this error ??

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

I have started getting exactly the same problem when running mvn: emma:emma on a project where running the same command was previously working fine.  I can narrow it down to the exact commit (which consists of a number of files) but there isn't anything strange or complex in the commit which jumps out as potentially causing running the Emma plugin to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the emma plugin, as it integrates Emma, [which hasn't been updated in nearly a decade](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emma/files/).  Even though it wasn't updated, it continued to work for years.

Eventually, [it was succeeded by EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/index.html), which eventually re-based itself on JaCoCo (Java Code Coverage).

So now, you want the [jacoco plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html), which has been updated to keep pace with Java Generics, and with the new functional interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin For Your answer.